# Get User Profile Picture RESTfull way

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, rest

I am working on building a PHP/Zend REST webservice and one of its "methods" is to retrieve a user profile (I would go let's say site.com/user/profile). All the user data is pretty much encoded as string (name, description, dob, ...) but I dont know how should I retrieve their image. What would be the best way to bring the user image and still be RESTfully complied? Should I have a specific method for the image or is there a way I could bring it all the data at once?

The pictures could be either saved in the file system or in the database, this should not matter on the implementation.

Comment: Don't sign your posts please; ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of options:
 - Use accept type header on the request to the same Uri. (site.com/user/profile), so a get with accept type json will bring their data, with jpg it would return the image. 
 - add additional resource identifier for the image, such as /user/profile/picture. The Uri for this resource should be supplied in the response for /user/profile

depends how you think of the picture, is it a different representation of the same resource, or a new resource.